# How to run VS Code program on command prompt?

Tags: cmd, command-prompt, visual-studio-code

New to both VS Code and Visual Studio... When I run my C# program in Visual Studio, the command prompt opens and the program is run there. In VS Code however, the program is run in the integrated debug console.

Is there a way I can set VS Code to open up cmd prompt and run my program there, rather than the VS Code debug console?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not about an issue with your provided code, it is about configuring a specific piece of software, and is therefore not an appropriate question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and search "Terminal: Explorer Kind". Then set it to external select external.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change your console to External console by my Example in launch.json

[image]